# Вывод информации из столбца в mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Как вывести информация из столбца в mysql.
Есть столбик test, в котором присутствует подобное содержание
`id|15||id2|20||id3|25`. Как вывести значение `id` отдельно, `$id=15` `$id2=20`?
Сейчас вывожу на DLE таким образов

```
$sql = $db->query( "SELECT * from dle_post where id=1);
$row = $db->get_row($sql);
echo $row['xfields'];
```

Мы получаем `id|15||id2|20||id3|25`, мне нужно вывести отдельно значение каждого id. Не массивом

Comment: Я не правильно выразился, в строке

Comment: Скорее отдельными полями в одной записи... впрочем, зависит от смысла данных.

Comment: Это cms DLE, дополнительные поля, они все добавляются в одну строку, каждое новое доп. поле добавляется через ||

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, чем вам не угодил массив, в нем как раз гораздо удобнее работать с неопределенным набором переменных.

```
...
$arr=array();
foreach(explode("||",$row['xfields']) as $x) {
  list($key,$val)=explode("|",$x);
  $arr[$key]=$val;
}
print_r($arr);
// Если нужны конкретные переменные можете их конечно получить:
$id=$arr['id']; $id2=$arr['id2']; ...
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает, просто с массивами не дружу, мне из xfields главное вывести первый `id`, все остальные мне не нужны.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы выделить "поле нумер N", используйте:

```
-- выделить название
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`field`,'|',3*N-2),'|',-1)
-- выделить значение 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`field`,'|',3*N-1),'|',-1)
```

Альтернативный вариант (для версии сервера 5.7.8 и старше):

```
CONCAT('{"', REPLACE(REPLACE(`field`,'||','","'),'|','":"') ,'"}')
```

и вот у тебя уже не хрень абы какая, а честный JSON...